# Setting Date and Time for QDateEdit and QTimeEdit

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, pyqt5, datetime

Working on a QGIS plugin, I am struggling to save/load date and time values. Users can enter dates via `QDateEdit` widget and times via `QTimeEdit` widget. Values are then stored the following:

```
s = QgsSettings()

# Date
self.Isochrones_Date_setting = self.dlg.Isochrones_Date.date()
s.setValue("otp_plugin/Isochrones_Date", self.Isochrones_Date_setting)
    
# Time
self.Isochrones_Time_setting = self.dlg.Isochrones_Time.time()
s.setValue("otp_plugin/Isochrones_Time", self.Isochrones_Time_setting)
```

and shall be read by:

```
s = QgsSettings()

# Date
self.Isochrones_Date_setting = s.value("otp_plugin/Isochrones_Date", QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
self.dlg.Isochrones_Date.setDateTime(self.Isochrones_Date_setting)
        
# Time
self.Isochrones_Time_setting = s.value("otp_plugin/Isochrones_Time", '14:00:00')
self.dlg.Isochrones_Time.setDateTime(self.Isochrones_Time_setting)
```

However, loading saved values or getting default values fails. With this code I am getting the error

> TypeError: setDateTime(self, Union[QDateTime, datetime.datetime]):
> argument 1 has unexpected type 'QDate'

What is the correct syntax, if not `.setDateTime()`? Or do I need to convert QDate to some other date before? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have to use `.setDate()` for `QDateEdit` and `.setTime()` for `QTimeEdit`, not `.setDateTime()` and convert strings to `QTime` via `QTime.fromString()` or to `QDate` via `QDate.fromString()`.

But: in this case it is a little more complicated, because `QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())` is in `QDateTime-Format`. So in this case, `QDateEdit`, has to be set using `.setDateTime()` but the stored setting from `QDateEdit` is in `QDate-Format`, so `.setDate()` has to be used. The simplest way to combine both possibilities, is to just use a `try/except` statement: it will always pick the stored one, if available, and only the standard one if no stored is available.

So the code would look like:

```
s = QgsSettings()

# Date
self.Isochrones_Date_setting = s.value("otp_plugin/Isochrones_Date", QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
try:
    self.dlg.Isochrones_Date.setDateTime(self.Isochrones_Date_setting) # Standard value
except:
    self.dlg.Isochrones_Date.setDate(self.Isochrones_Date_setting) # Stored value
        
# Time
self.Isochrones_Time_setting = s.value("otp_plugin/Isochrones_Time", QTime.fromString('14:00:00'))
self.dlg.Isochrones_Time.setTime(self.Isochrones_Time_setting)
```